# GetDiskFreeSpaceEx with compressed disk

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, diskspace

I want to get the free space on a compressed disk to show it to a end user. I'm using C++, MFC on Windows 2000 and later. The Windows API offers the `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` function.

However, this function seems to return the "uncompressed" sized of the data. This cause me some problem.

For example :
 - Disk size is 100 GB
 - Data size is 90 GB
 - Compressed data size is 80 GB

The user will see that the disk is 90% full, but in reality, it is only 80% full.

---

**EDIT**

As Gleb pointed out, the function is returning the good information.

So here is the new question : is there a way to get both the compressed size and the uncompressed one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to map over all files, query with **GetFileSize()** and **GetCompressedFileSize()** and sum them up. Use **GetFileAttributes()** to know if a file is compressed or not, in case only parts of the whole volume is compressed, which might certainly be the case.

> Hum, so that's not a trivial
>   operation. I suppose I must implement
>   some mechanism to avoid querying all
>   files size all the time. I mean ... if
>   I have a 800GB hard drive, it could
>   take some very long time to get all
>   file size.

True.

Perhaps start off by a full scan (application startup) and populate your custom data structure, e.g. a hash/map from file name to file data struct/class, then poll the drive with **FindFirstChangeNotification()** and update your internal structure accordingly.

You might also want to read about "Change Journals". I have never used them myself so don't know how they work, but might be worth checking out.

Comment: Hum, so that's not a trivial operation. I suppose I must implement some mechanism to avoid querying all files size all the time.
I mean ... if I have a 800GB hard drive, it could take some very long time to get all file size.

Comment: Added a comment to your note. See my post.

Answer (score 1):

The function returns the amount of free space correctly. It can be demonstrated by using this simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main() {
    ULARGE_INTEGER p1, p2, p3;
    GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(".", &p1, &p2, &p3);
    printf("%llu %llu %llu\n", p1, p2, p3);
}
```

After compressing a previously uncompressed directory the free space grows.

So what are you talking about?